# Exception: The starting row of the range is too small

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this code to search column 1 on a spreadsheet for the value 'Net Income'. I want this code to return the row position of with the value 'Net Income' so I can apply some formatting specific to that row based on that value. Here's the code I currently have:

```
const netIncomeRow = values.reduce((pos, row, i) => {
    if(row[0] === 'Net Income') pos = i + 1
    return pos;
  },0);

  const netIncomeRange = sheet.getRange(netIncomeRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  netIncomeRange.setFontWeight('bold');
```

When I run the code, I get the error "Exception: The starting row of the range is too small." and cannot figure out how to fix this ):

*Edit - I was taught to search through the rows this way as the position of the 'Net Income' row will change over time and I would like the bold formatting to follow and apply to whatever row ends up with the value 'Net Income'.

Comment: Probably `netIncomeRow` is zero. You can add `console.log(netIncomeRow)` and see.

Comment: That's what I did about 10 minutes ago and you are right, it comes back as 0. Do you know how I can correct this??

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions?

Comment: I vote to close. Since there is no feedback and the problem looks irreproducible.

Answer (score 0):

#### Prevent Error

```
const netIncomeRow = values.reduce((pos, row, i) => {
    if(row[0] === 'Net Income') pos = i + 1
    return pos;
  },0);
  if(netIncomeRow) {
    const netIncomeRange = sheet.getRange(netIncomeRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    netIncomeRange.setFontWeight('bold');
  }
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for the answer! The answer allows the code to run without breaking, but does not apply the bold formatting to the row with the 'Net Income' value.

Comment: Well maybe it has something to do with the netIncomeRange that you wrote and I have not information about

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an index of a value in array you can use the method `array.findIndex()`. Something like this:

```
const netIncomeRow = values.findIndex(x => x[0] == 'Net Income');
```

Here is the function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var index = values.findIndex(x => x[0]== 'Net Income') + 1;

  if (index) sh.getRange(index,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setFontWeight('Bold');
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yuri! When I use the above answer, t console.log(netIncomeRow) returns as -1 breaks with the same error

Comment: How the `values` look like? Show example of your sheet, and how exactly you're getting the `values`. Right now it looks like the array doesn't have 'Net Income' among its elements

Comment: I've updated my answer.